# Date range not working in aggregation pipeline, but works in find()

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I am trying to filter data by a date range. Example return the data that was created no more than 14 days ago.

I can do this in find with the following:

```
{
    $match: {
        eventTime: { $gte: startTime.toDate(), $lte: endTime.toDate() }
    }
}
```

eventTime is an ISO date as well as startTime and endTime

I am using an aggregation and a lookup and trying to implement the same thing:

```
{
            $lookup:
            {
                from: "data",
                let: { dataId: "$dataId", patientId: "$patientId" },
                pipeline: [
                    {
                        $match:
                        {
                            $expr:
                            {
                                $and:
                                    [
                                        { $eq: ["$patientId", patientId] },
                                        { $eq: ["$dataId", "$$dataId"] },
                                        { $gte: ["$eventTime", startTime.toDate()] },
                                        { $lte: ["$eventTime", endTime.toDate()] },
                                    ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                as: "data"
            }
        }
```

But no data results are returned. If I remove the dates I get all the correct data based on dataId and patient. so the join is working.. but somehow the date range is not.

Again both the eventTime and startTime and endTime are all ISO dates.
example :

```
let endTime = Moment(new Date());
let startTime = Moment().subtract(days, "days");

"eventTime": "2019-08-07T03:37:40.738Z"

 startTime  "2019-07-30T00:02:11.611Z"
 endTime  "2019-08-13T00:02:11.610Z"

End time is 'today' 
so in the example here the data time is between the two dates and should be returned.
```

I looked there : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gte/
and it should work.. but not the case

I tried:

```
{eventTime: { '$gte': new Date(startTime), $lte: new Date(endTime)}}
and I get:
MongoError: An object representing an expression must have exactly one field: { $gte: new Date(1564495211043), $lte: new Date(1565704811042) }
```

also tried:

```
{ eventTime: {'$gte': new Date(startTime)}}

and get:

MongoError: Expression $gte takes exactly 2 arguments. 1 were passed in.
```

also tried:

```
{ $eventTime: {'$gte': new Date(startTime)}}, {$eventTime: {'$lte': new Date(endTime)}}

and get: MongoError: Unrecognized expression '$eventTime'
```

Any insight would certainly be appreciated

Comment: What is the end time u r putting?

Comment: Don't you think $gte and $lte queries will come in a single object as shown in ur 1st query ..U have used them in separate objects in lookup query

Comment: I added the end time. I was not able to figure how to enable combine them into a single query inside the 'and' .. the docs show them as separate for some reason.

Comment: Are you sure event time is an iso date object and not an iso string?

Comment: try this $and: [{$eventTime: {'$gte': new Date(startTime)}}, {$eventTime: {'$lte': new Date(endTime)}}]

Comment: Tried that.. for some reason in an aggregation it does not like the field name as the first parameter. I tried a few more approaches and all syntax error. I may have etc break this up into a find statement. I don't think mongo likes this somehow :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get it working via toDate:

```
{
                        $match:
                        {
                            $expr:
                            {
                                $and:
                                    [
                                        { $eq: ["$patientId", patientId] },
                                        { $eq: ["$dataId", "iraeOverallAlert"] },
                                        { "$gte": [ {$toDate: "$eventTime"}, startTime.toDate()] },
                                        { "$lte": [ {$toDate: "$eventTime"}, endTime.toDate()] },

                                    ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
```

Note: This was not needed in the find, but somehow was needed using aggregation. Makes no sense but yah for trial and error.